# How to make a cube rotation effect in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I don't need a complete cube implementation but I would like to have two views, one for the front face and one for the top, and be able to rotate it towards the user anchored on the front face's bottom edge.

I have this:

```
struct TestView: View {
@State private var value: Double = 0

var angle: Double {
    10 + 75 * value
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        Color.orange
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .rotation3DEffect(
                .degrees(-angle + 90 ),
                axis: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0),
                anchor: .bottom,
                perspective: 0.3
            )
        
        Color.red
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
    .rotation3DEffect(
        .degrees(-angle),
        axis: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0),
        anchor: .bottom,
        perspective: 0.3
    )
    
    Slider(value: $value, in: 0.0...1.0, step: 0.1)
        .padding()
   }
}
```

The slider value (0.0-1.0) drives the angle changes (10 to 85 degrees). The outer rotation effect does the right thing to the red face. I have the orange face inside the rotated VStack because I need the connected edges to be affected equally (getting wider as the cube rotates forward).

What I try to do in the inner rotation effect is to have the orange view rotate back 90 degrees but that doesn't work because it gets combined with the outer effect resulting in an incorrect shape. See the third stage of this demo which looks totally off:

[image: demo showing three states of the rotating cube]

I tried applying rotation to either face independently but I wasn't able to make the edges match width and stay connected.

Ideas to fix this? thanks...

**Edit**

I made some progress by using matchedGeometryEffect. This way I can keep both views connected and have the rotation effects independent.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var value: Double = 0
    @Namespace private var cubeNS
    
    var degrees: Double {
        value * 90
    }
    
    var radians: Double {
        value * (Double.pi / 2)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Color.orange
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .rotation3DEffect(
                    .degrees(-degrees + 90 ),
                    axis: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0),
                    anchor: .bottom,
                    perspective: 0.25
                )
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "cube", in: cubeNS, properties: .position, anchor: .bottom, isSource: false)
                .scaleEffect(1 + sin(radians) * 0.32) // <-- 

            
            Color.red
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "cube", in: cubeNS, properties: .position, anchor: .top, isSource: true)
                .rotation3DEffect(
                    .degrees(-degrees),
                    axis: (x: 1.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0),
                    anchor: .bottom,
                    perspective: 0.25
                )
        }
        Slider(value: $value, in: 0.0...0.95, step: 0.05)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

The problem is I had to use a hack with a magic number (0.32 here but depends on the perspective) to match the width, since matchedGeometryEffect won't give me an adjusted frame for the rotated red face.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, depending on the current angle the orange face can be a bit smaller or a big larger than it should.

Wondering if any of you comes up with the final piece of this puzzle! It looks pretty good until one notices that bit...

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://trailingclosure.com/cube-rotation-transition/)? Also I don't know if your goal is just learning SwiftUI, but if you are actually trying to make rotating cube for production app, I would suggest to consider something more graphically robust. [Apple has a great example with Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/rotating_a_cube_by_transforming_its_vertices), or [Metal](https://www.kodeco.com/728-metal-tutorial-with-swift-3-part-2-moving-to-3d?page=2#toc-anchor-008).

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't adapt it to what I need. The fact that the anchor is the front face's bottom edge makes it a different kind of challenge. If the rotation goes from 0 to 90 degrees, the top face should be bigger than what the front face was initially.
This is for a feature I need in a production app that is mostly SwiftUI; Accelerate and Metal are rather alien to me! Thanks for your comment

Comment: I don't think this would be possible unless you know exactly what the `perspective:` parameter is doing. You would need to find the apparent height of the red square after rotation, and then vertically `offset` the orange square according to that height. You can also just handwrite your own rotation + projection matrix, so that you know how to calculate the apparent height. Or, just use SceneKit.

Comment: `GeometryEffect` is probably a good tool for this